# Надо выбрать id нужной таблицы из двух таблиц

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть код

```
<div class="admin_div">
    <?php
        include 'db_doc_2.php';
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_base", $db_user, $db_pass);
        $db->exec("set names utf8");
        $db_id = $_GET['id'];
        
    
        $sql = "SELECT $db_table.id, $db_table.menu_name, $db_table_2.id, $db_table_2.text, $db_table_2.parent
                    FROM $db_table LEFT JOIN $db_table_2 ON $db_table.id = $db_table_2.id
                    WHERE $db_table.id = $db_id ";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch()){
    ?>

    <div class="news">
        <div class="news_main_block">
            <div class="news_title">
                <p><?php echo $row['menu_name'] ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="news_post">
                <a href="doc_update_text.php?id=<?php echo $db_id ?>">Изменить текст</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="all_post">
            <div class="post_main">
                <form action="doc_create_text_conn.php?id=<?php echo $db_id ?>" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="<?php echo $db_id ?>">
                    <div id="sample">
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="//js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> 
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
                        </script>
                        <textarea name="text" rows="15" style="width:100%; height:150px;" value="<?php echo $row['text'] ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button class="mail_submit" name="btn" type="submit">Изменить содержание</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

<?php 
    }
?>
```

Чтобы вывести написанный текст, нужно выбрать id именно $db_table_2, а как это сделать я хз :D

```
  <a href="doc_update_text.php?id=<?php echo $db_id ?>">Изменить текст</a>
```

Вставить id таблицы $db_table_2 нужно здесь

Comment: $db_table_2.id AS id2

Comment: и обязательно почитать про то как **правильно** пользоваться ПДО чтобы избежать ошибок и инъекций